# ReverseMatch error in Django password reset views

Tags: django

I have been following some online tutorial on how to setup the Django email reset views but I still get the reverse match error:

```
Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'uidb36': '2', 'token': '3fk-e9d14405e0aaf252475e'}' not found
```

My URLs setting are like this:

```
url(r'^login_retrieval/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', 
    {'post_reset_redirect' : '/login_retrieval_done/',
     'template_name' : 'core/password_reset_form.html'}),
url(r'^login_retrieval_done/', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'),
url(r'^password_reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', 
    {'post_reset_redirect' : '/user/password/done/'}),
url(r'^user/password/done/$', 
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
```

I can get to the email address input page but when I click send email, it just returns the reverse match error.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a shortcut way on that, you just need one url

Comment: Here is a good tutorial for that, from my boss http://www.nerdydork.com/implementing-a-forgot-password-feature-on-a-django-site.html

Comment: If you don't understand the tutorial just tell me I will post the step by step process

Comment: Could you show the part of the code where you're using the reverse() helper?

Comment: just now, I have the same problem, did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated to Django 1.6 or above?

If so, you just have to replace `uidb36` with `uidb64`. This applies to `{% url ... %}` calls in templates, `reverse()` calls in Python code and the regexes in your urls.py.

Picking one example from your urls.py:

```
url(r'^password_reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', 
    {'post_reset_redirect' : '/user/password/done/'}),
```

See [Django 1.6 Release Notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.6/#django-contrib-auth-password-reset-uses-base-64-encoding-of-user-pk)